# Не работает transition с background: cover

Tags: javascript, html, css

Помогите решить проблему, а именно не срабатывает transition с css правилом, которое в моем случае нельзя изменять background-size: cover 
вот код (на другой ресурс не могу загрузить сейчас):

```
<div class = "bkg"></div>
<style>
.bkg{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black; 
  background: url(../img/image.png);
  background-size: cover;
  transition: 1s;
}

.bkg:hover{
  background-size:300px 300px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Значение cover не может быть использовано для css анимации. Вы можете использовать вместо cover 100% 100% (по смыслу тоже самое), а при `:hover` делать их 120% 120% например.

```
<div class = "bkg"></div>
<style>
.bkg{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black; 
  background: url(../img/image.png);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  transition: 1s;
}

.bkg:hover{
  background-size:120% 120%;
}
</style>
```

Comment: При background-size: 100% 100% не соблюдается пропорциональность сторон фонового изображения, в отличии от background: cover

Comment: Тогда можно использовать `transform: scale(1.2, 1.2)` внутри псевдо класса hover, правда не во всех версиях браузеров сработает